# String character swap

Tags: java, arrays

I have problem with character swap in string.
e.g. I have string "sdgk4e5s3gj6ds3h6fggh" and I need code that can swap numbers with character.

The result should look something like this: "sdgke4s5g3jd6sh3f6ggh"
I have got to the point where I make char array out of String, but I don't know what to do next. Any help?

Comment: Your problem is that you are not even able to express your requirements. It is **not all clear** how to transform your input to get to the given output. And then: even if those rules would be clear: this is not a "we do your homework for you" service. You start by showing us **your** code; and by asking specific questions about programming problems with that code.

Comment: From the I/O given I assume you want to swap each number with the **preceding** character. So you simply [loop](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm) through your made `char array` and whenever you encounter a number, you wrap it with the previously read character.

Comment: If you have done any work on this, sharing the code will help everyone. Someone may be able to help you build on top of your existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are asking, a simple regex could solve your problem:

```
String result = "sdgk4e5s3gj6ds3h6fggh".replaceAll("(\\d)(\\D)", "$2$1")
```

which basically inverts 2 characters every time it finds one digit followed by one non-digit.